# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined, how to check if parameter can be split?

Tags: javascript

I was working on this Title Case kata on Codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5202ef17a402dd033c000009/train/javascript

First, I was struggling to pass this test

```
titleCase("First a of in", "an often into");
```

but after I fixed that I started to get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

The problem is it doesn't say which test I am failing, I guess problem is when they give only one word as title parameter?

I am making different checks in my if statement, but nothing helps. Here is my current version:

```
function titleCase(title, minorWords) {
  let minorWordsArray = [];
  minorWordsArray.push(minorWords.split(" "));

  if (title.includes(" ") && title != null && title != undefined) {
    return title
      .split(" ")
      .map((word, index) => {
        if (
          minorWordsArray.length &&
          minorWordsArray.includes(word.toLowerCase()) &&
          index != 0
        ) {
          return word.toLowerCase();
        }
        return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
      })
      .join(" ");
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: There are only two calls for `.split()`: `minorWords.split(" ")`, `title.split(" ")` - `title` can not be `undefined`, hence...

Comment: _"I was working on this..."_ - A question on SO should contain all necessary information and not rely on any external resource, like a link to a Codewars task. -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: learn to debug: add a `console.log(minorWords);` to the function and see why it can't be split

Comment: i clicked your link and found that in lines 3 and 6 of the assertions minorWords is actually undefined

Comment: so answer to your question "What am I missing here?": a check if minorWords is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. `(minorWords||'')` returns `''` (empty string) if `minorWords` is `undefined`, otherwise `minorWords`.

```
function titleCase(title, minorWords) {
  return title
    .split(' ')
    .map((x,i) => (i&&(minorWords||'').toLowerCase().split(' ').includes(x.toLowerCase()))?
         x.toLowerCase():
         x?(x[0].toUpperCase()+x.slice(1).toLowerCase()):'')
    .join(' ');
}
```